# Programmatically check if mic on Android is currently in use

Tags: android

There is a way to check if microphone on Android phone is recording anything?
I didn't find anything in AudioRecorder.
**Update:**

```
int sampleRateInHz = 8000;//8000 44100, 22050 and 11025
int channelConfig = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO;
int audioFormat = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;
int bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(sampleRateInHz, channelConfig, audioFormat);


public int getRecordingState() {
    AudioRecord audioRecord = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT, sampleRateInHz, channelConfig, audioFormat, bufferSize);
    return audioRecord.getRecordingState();
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22677749/how-to-check-if-android-microphone-is-available-for-use

Comment: I tried that already. It always returns true...

Answer (score 0):

I saw a number of things you could try. From `AudioRecord` - `getRecordingState()` - Returns the recording state of the AudioRecord instance.

Or you can try testing:  `read(byte[], int, int)`, `read(short[], int, int)` or `read(ByteBuffer, int)` methods to see if the buffers are growing in size.

**Edit:** Here are some examples on how to read the buffer and an explanation:

[Understanding of the Audio Recorder read() buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21986385/understanding-of-the-audio-recorder-read-buffer)

[Android AudioRecord example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499042/android-audiorecord-example)

Comment: So I wrote the method (see update please). Doesn't look like work either. It always returns 1, i.e. int RECORDSTATE_STOPPED...